# Xcode/iOS NSUserDefaults acting Strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am attempting my first save project with NSUserDefaults, and something strange is happening.

In my app delegate, before doing anything too much, I am toggling a couple of variables.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]){
    //flag doesnt exist then this IS the first run
    self.firstRun = TRUE;

    NSLog(@"FIRST RUN");

    //store the flag so it exists the next time the app starts
    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];
    NSLog(@"%s world2 before",[defaults objectForKey:@"world2"] ? "true" : "false" );
    [defaults setBool:false forKey:@"world2"];
    NSLog(@"%s world2 after",[defaults objectForKey:@"world2"] ? "true" : "false" );
}else{
    //flag does exist so this ISNT the first run
    self.firstRun = FALSE;
    NSLOG(@"NOT FIRST RUN");
    NSLog(@"%s world2",[defaults objectForKey:@"world2"] ? "true" : "false" );

}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Doing so, When I run the application, this is what I get in console (on first run)

```
2014-09-09 22:15:57.794 GameName[30151:907] FIRST RUN
2014-09-09 22:15:57.795 GameName[30151:907] false world2 before
2014-09-09 22:15:57.795 GameName[30151:907] true world2 after
```

What I don't understand is why before setting it to false, it is false (sure, okay) - but AFTER setting it to false, it is true! Merr?

I have also tried setting to true, YES, NO, as well as using NSNumber with Bool.

My full app delegate:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameLevelLayer.h"
@interface AppController : CCAppDelegate
{
    GameLevelLayer *currentLevel;
}
@property(nonatomic) BOOL firstRun;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CCBuilderReader.h"


@implementation AppController
@synthesize firstRun = _firstRun;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:        (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Configure Cocos2d with the options set in SpriteBuilder
    NSString* configPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Published-iOS"]; // TODO: add support for Published-Android support
    configPath = [configPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"configCocos2d.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary* cocos2dSetup = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:configPath];

    // Note: this needs to happen before configureCCFileUtils is called, because we need apportable to correctly setup the screen scale factor.
#ifdef APPORTABLE
    if([cocos2dSetup[CCSetupScreenMode] isEqual:CCScreenModeFixed])
        [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode = [UIScreenMode emulatedMode:UIScreenAspectFitEmulationMode];
    else
    [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode = [UIScreenMode emulatedMode:UIScreenScaledAspectFitEmulationMode];
#endif

    // Configure CCFileUtils to work with SpriteBuilder
    [CCBReader configureCCFileUtils];

    // Do any extra configuration of Cocos2d here (the example line changes the pixel format for faster rendering, but with less colors)
    //[cocos2dSetup setObject:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 forKey:CCConfigPixelFormat];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]){
        //flag doesnt exist then this IS the first run
        self.firstRun = TRUE;

        NSLog(@"FIRST RUN");

        //store the flag so it exists the next time the app starts
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];
        NSLog(@"%s world2 before",[defaults objectForKey:@"world2"] ? "true" : "false" );
        [defaults setBool:false forKey:@"world2"];
        NSLog(@"%s world2 after",[defaults objectForKey:@"world2"] ? "true" : "false" );
    }else{
        //flag does exist so this ISNT the first run
        self.firstRun = FALSE;
        NSLog(@"NOT FIRST RUN");
        NSLog(@"%s world2",[defaults objectForKey:@"world2"] ? "true" : "false" );

    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self setupCocos2dWithOptions:cocos2dSetup];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It would be more constructive if you had logged the value returned. Look at the actual data!

Comment: Log the value returned? Not sure what you mean >.<

Comment: Log: [defaults objectForKey:@"world2"] like: `NSLog(@"%@ world2 after", [defaults objectForKey:@"world2"]);`

Comment: Dur pa Dur! *facepalm* Thanks you so very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the log condition is incorrect. You are setting the value using "setBool" method. While retrieving you used "objectForKey" method.

```
[defaults objectForKey:@"world2"] ? "true" : "false";
```

The above line returns "true", because it checks whether the user defaults has the value for key "world2". So, change that line to

```
 [defaults boolForKey:@"world2"] ? "true" : "false"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, trying to push through this stuff defiantly doesn't work. This will teach me to pay more attention! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
- (BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

not:

```
- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

The latter returns an object, that represents false so the test in the `NSLog()` reports true meaning that something was returned.

So the code would be:

```
[defaults boolForKey:@"world2"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, trying to push through this stuff defiantly doesn't work. This will teach me to pay more attention! I appreciate it. Wish I could accept both answers!